# HTTPS secure connection configuration for asp.net web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, https

I have developed one site in asp.net (C#).

Now, I want to access my site with https://www.mysite.com & `https://localhost/mywebsite`

Please suggest me how to config the secure connection.

And, for this need to config in IIS-Manager level or Can we manage in code level also?

Can any one please suggest me.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Are you hosting your local site on IIS?

Comment: You need to configure SSL in the IIS. In your code you can enforce redirects to a SSL version of your site. At least that's how I've done it in the past with VS 2010, IIS 7.5, ASP.Net Webforms

Answer (score 0):

if you are hosting your local site (dev version) on IIS then:

1. Go to IIS Manager, click on the top node (your server name)
2. in the section on the right, double click on Server Certificates
3. in the Actions pane on far right, click on "Create Self-Signed Certificate"
4. give your certificate a name e.g.: "MyDevCert", and click okay
5. right click on your IIS WebSite, and choose "Edit Bindings"
6. click on "ADD" button
7. choose https from Type dropdown, then choose your newly created certificate in this case "MyDevCert" from the SSL certificate drop down
8. press okay, press close ... restart IIS

you should now be able to browser to `https://localhost`